# Ubuntu terminal re-partitioning to increase the "root" partition size

Tags: partitioning, unallocated

My root partition size is not enough for me and should be increased in order to allow me adding some new application and services (e.g. mongodb). I got some more free space and I can see it when I type `print free` in the GNU parted tool:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
        256MB   257MB   1048kB            Free Space
 2      257MB   8589MB  8332MB  extended
 5      257MB   8589MB  8332MB  logical                lvm
        8589MB  17.2GB  8591MB            Free Space
```

My space partiotning looks like:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  3.7G  2.6G  923M  74% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        396M  520K  395M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none                         100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M   66M  158M  30% /boot
```

(`df -h` in the command line)

Any easy and quick way to allocate more space to my root partition? ( I guess it's /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root)

Comment: how does this look in Gparted? Can you give an image of your partitions?

Comment: I guess Gparted is a graphic tool. I have only terminal access to this server.